# How can I change the display name for Django admin filter_horizontal

Tags: django, django-admin

Assume I have a product object and category object with many-to-many relation. I want to use filter_horizontal to edit them in admin page. How can I change the text display in the form by category object 1 to the text of category except override `__str__` in the model? Because I don't want to this change globally.

I try to use customer `label_from_instance` from ModelMultipleChoiceField class, but this will break filter_horizontal.

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ['categories']
```

Comment: I would have used `label_from_instance`, why does it break? Or what exactly breaks?

Comment: @dirkgroten it will break filter_horizontal's sytle, make it become a regular select widget

Comment: How did you implement it? Show the code. Your form field is probably overriding the widget, if you don't set the widget in the field itself. Set the widget to FilteredSelectMultiple.